# Pasting functions together

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Suppose there is a countable (or assume finite, if necessary) collection of convex and open sets $B_i\subset R^n$. Suppose $\cup B_i$ is an open and convex set. For each $B_i$, $f_i:B_i\to R$ is a function (convex function, but I guess convexity is not important here), satisfying $\forall i,j$, $f_i-f_j$ is affine on $B_i\cap B_j$.

Does there exist a function $f:\cup B_i\to R$ s.t. $\forall i$, $f-f_i$ is affine on $B_i$? If not, is there any weaker analogous result?

On the high level, can we paste functions that are defined on small sets together up to tilting in a consistent way?